# A riddle with classes, inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

```
class A{
public:
     virtual void print() const { cout << "a" << endl; }
};

class B : public A{
    void print() const { cout << "b" << endl; }
};

void f(const A& a) {
    a.print();
}

int main() {
    A* a = new B;
    f(*a);
    return 0;
}
```

How should I change this peace of code, only the signature of func f and body of class A, so it would be printed "c", without changing anything else in this code.

**Edit:**
The first part was like:

```
class A{
    void print() const { cout << "a" << endl; }
};

void f(const A& a) {
    a.print();
}
```

How to add code, change signature of f and moderate body of A, so the string "b" will be printed.

And the second question, how to change only the signature of f from he first solution, so it would be printed a (for those two question the answer is the inheritance, virtual and polymorphism.

**WARNING**
Ok, the exact words are we can change the signature of f and make an addition to class A, so I don't sure, but I think we cannot change "a" to "c".

Comment: I think you got some detail wrong in copying from your homework assignment to your post.  But posting a homework assignment with no evidence you even tried to do it yourself is not appropriate even if you had copied it correctly.

Comment: I think those functions should be marked virtual.  Otherwise all you need to do is change `cout << "a" << endl;` to `cout << "c" << endl;`

Comment: Have you heard about politeness and typo ? The person who answered down below had.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only allowed to change the **signature** of func `f` and **body** of class `A`, you have to do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
     virtual void print() const { cout << "c" << endl; }
                                        // ^ changed body "a" -> "c"
};

class B : public A{
    void print() const { cout << "b" << endl; }
};

void f( A a ) {
      // ^ changed signature: removed & and const (const can optionally be removed)
    a.print();
}

int main() {
    A* a = new B;
    f(*a);
    return 0;
}
```

Parameter to `f` is passed by value, so `*a` is copied to parameter `A a` of function `f`. The type of the parameter is `A` and so `a.print` calls `A::print`.

With regard to your change of question, if you are not allowed to change `"a"` to `"c"`, you have to add an overloaded methode `print` which is not `const`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:

     virtual void print() { cout << "c" << endl; }
     //           ^^^^^  ^ add function print (without const)

     virtual void print() const { cout << "a" << endl; }
};

class B : public A{
    void print() const { cout << "b" << endl; }
};

void f( A & a ) {
    // ^ change signature -> remove const
    a.print();
}

int main() {
    A* a = new B;
    f(*a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you've changed here also class B's body.

Comment: That is what I thought about in the beginning, but seemed to be trivial, so I'm thinking about less trivial, but sophisticated solution.

Comment: Why did you remove the reference?  There is no need to as the object gets sliced regardlessly.

Comment: Nathan, that is what suspicious, because in the question do says about the signature of f to be changed, otherwise we just put down the virtual and were through. And adding the virtual is the first part of the question, so I suspect it isn't the issue that the author want me to solve.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ah.  It was not when the OP first posted and I did not see they changed it.

Comment: I've added an innovation for this riddle. We cannot change class A, but only add to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Replace `cout` to output 'c' in `A::print`, change signature of `f()` to accept parameter by value.